# Author.php not displaying post type posts

Tags: custom-post-types, author-template

I note that the twentyeleven theme author.php template  only display the posts from normal posts, the custom post type posts are not display in this template. How do I query all the posts from the author regardless the post type?

I tried

```
global $wp_query;       
$theauthorid  =   get_current_user_id( );
query_posts( 'author=' . $theauthorid );
```

but it also doesn't display post type post. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it...

by query all the post types

```
$arg = array('post_type'=> array ('cpt','post'),);
query_posts( $arg);
```